# How do I delete other subdirectories when doing git filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

The directory structure in my current repo is

```
kaal-client\
 desktop\
 chrome-extension\
 native-host\
```

I want to separate the subdirectories into their own repo's. So for this I ran the following command:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter chrome-extension master --all
```

This correctly copies the contents of chrome-extension to kaal-client\ and does delete most files that existed in that directory. But it does not delete the desktop\ and native-host\ directories and also the file npm-debug.log.

Should it not delete these directories and files which are not inside chrome-extension\ ?

======================

EDIT 1: The file npm-debug.log is untracked, which is probably why that is not deleted.

EDIT 2: I notice that while the other subdirectories are not deleted, the files within them were. And when I do a git status, they show as untracked. So i just delete them and continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do after the filter-branch, in order to go on from a clean state is:

```
git clean -fndx
```

(note the 'n' dry-run option: it will *print* what would be deleted. If you agree, do a [`git clean -fdx`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) to remove what you don't need anymore)